# Java update binary save files to latest version of my app

Tags: java, serialization, file-io, updates

I'm creating a desktop app in which users can save their files. I save them as serialized binary files of custom classes. My problem is, every time I change the code for the custom classes, the serialized files are out of date and don't work anymore.

My app is ready for its first release, but I plan on releasing updates. How can I update the custom classes without corrupting the user's save files from version 1?

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Don't use serialization to save the data.

Comment: What should I use?

Comment: Whatever you want. Just make sure to keep the data forwards compatible and the data model backwards compatible (to a certain limit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your own serialization format for your data model. For example, you could use JSON, or XML, or any other formats. There are also frameworks for automating this process (for example: https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/ - for Java-to-XML, http://json-b.net/ - Java-to-JSON).
This way your implementation is decoupled from the serialisation format. First, instance, no need to change serialisation format when only the behaviour of your class changed. Second, this gives you a possibility in your application to implement mechanism for updating the files from older versions to the latest.

Comment: Thank you! I'll check out those links.

Comment: How do I add the repositories and dependencies to my "Maven Project" in Netbeans 8?